# Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/login.xhtml' for action '#{admin.Validity}' with outcome 'failure'

Tags: jsf

I can't get it to work. i get the following:

```
Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/login.xhtml' for action '#{admin.Validity}' with outcome 'failure'
```

this is the code i'm using:

HTML:

```
<div id="main" >

        <h:form id="login_form">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><h:outputText value="User: " /></td>
                    <td><h:inputText id="username"
                            value="#{admin.username}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><h:outputText value="Password: " /></td>
                    <td><h:inputSecret id="password"
                            value="#{admin.password}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><h:commandButton value="Login" type="submit"
                            action="#{admin.Validity}" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </h:form>

    </div>
```

Admin.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;


@ManagedBean(name="admin")
@SessionScoped
public class Admin implements Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
Boolean authenticated;
String username;
String password;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String Validity() {
    if(username.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin")) {
        authenticated=true;
        return "success";
    }   else   {
        authenticated=false;
        return "failure";
    }
}

}
```

faces-config.xml

```
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>

    <navigation-case>
       <from-action>#{Admin.Validity}</from-action>
       <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
       <to-view-id>/main.xhtml</to-view-id>
       <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>

    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{Admin.Validity}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>failure</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

thank you. 
Y

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your managed bean is named `#{admin}`,

```
@ManagedBean(name="admin")
```

however you attempted to access it as `#{Admin}` in the navigation case,

```
<from-action>#{Admin.Validity}</from-action>
```

so it definitely won't work. Java is case sensitive.

Fix the managed bean name in the navigation case accordingly:

```
<from-action>#{admin.Validity}</from-action>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you've several minor design mistakes.

1. Managed bean name already defaults to the classname with 1st character lowercased. So your `@ManagedBean(name="admin")` can just be replaced by `@ManagedBean`.

   ```
   @ManagedBean
   @SessionScoped
   public class Admin implements Serializable {
   ```
2. [Method names should not start with uppercase](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367). Replace `Validity()` by `validity()`. Further there's also a grammatical/language mistake in the method name, but that's probably the language barrier. You'd normally have named it `validate()` or in this context better `authenticate()` or something.
3. Navigation cases are soo JSF 1.x. Since JSF 2.0 you can utilize the new "implicit navigation" feature. You can use the outcome value as mapping/extension-less view ID.

   ```
   public String authenticate() {
       if (username.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin")) {
           authenticated=true;
           return "main";
       } else {
           authenticated=false;
           return "login";
       }
   }
   ```

   This way you can remove the whole `<navigation-rule>` block altogether.

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html)

Answer (score 0):

In order to have navigation rules to work properly, make sure you also define .xhtml as the default extension for facelet files.  I added the following line to my web.xml and it solved a navigation problem.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Ref : http://www.coderanch.com/t/570654/JSF/java/Error-navigation

Answer (score -2):

Problem solved! i'm using jsf2 btw.

I've removed the following line from faces-config.xml

```
<from-action>#{Admin.Validity}</from-action>
```

thats it. hope this helps someone